# MathNet - Least computationally expensive way of extracting a large submatrix from a large matrix

Tags: vb.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm trying to extract a large submatrix from a parent matrix using the MathNet package. I couldn't find a builtin function to do it so i wrote this simple function in VB.net:

```
Private Function Extract(s As Matrix, RowsAndColumns As Int32()) As SparseMatrix
    Dim Sadj = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.SparseMatrix.Build.Sparse(RowsAndColumns.Count, RowsAndColumns.Count)
    For i = 0 To RowsAndColumns.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To RowsAndColumns.Count - 1
            Sadj(i, j) = s(RowsAndColumns (i), RowsAndColumns (j))
        Next
    Next
    Return Sadj
End Function
```

However, the performance of this function is very slow because typically the original matrix is very big and the submatrix is close to it in size. So i am looking at possible ways of optimizing this. Any help would be appreciated.

As a bit of a background, i am trying to extract a submatrix from a big sparse matrix and then to use CSparse to solve a large system of equations.

```
Dim Sred = Extract(S, FreeDOFs)
Dim storage = DirectCast(Sred.Storage, MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.SparseCompressedRowMatrixStorage(Of Double)) ' Get CSR storage.
Dim A = New CSparse.Double.SparseMatrix(Sred.ColumnCount, Sred.ColumnCount) With {.ColumnPointers = storage.RowPointers, .RowIndices = storage.ColumnIndices, .Values = storage.Values} ' Create CSparse matrix and Assign storage arrays.      
For i = 0 To NumofLoadCases - 1
    Dim Fred = Extract(NodeLoads.Item(ASP.AnalysisLoadCases.Keys(i)) - Pf.Item(ASP.AnalysisLoadCases.Keys(i)), FreeDOFs)
    Dim Dred = Sred.LU().Solve(Fred)
    Dvec.Add(ASP.AnalysisLoadCases.Keys(i), ReverseExtract(Dred, FreeDOFs, 6 * NumOfNodes))
Next
```

Comment: After a little noseying around in MathNet, this might work .. `Sadj = s.submatrix(0, RowsAndColumns.Count - 1, 0, RowsAndColumns.Count - 1)`, though, I know nothing about MathNet, I just err.. found it in the documentation here - https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex/Matrix.htm#SubMatrix - Search for submatrix in the page

Comment: David, thanks for your help. I need to extract most rows and columns but not all of them. Sorry, maybe i wasn't 100% clear.

Comment: No worries - like I said. I'm not that familiar with it all - just took a shot :-)

Comment: When you say most rows and columns, do you not mean a contiguous block that is a sub matrix then?

Comment: For example, say the original matrix is called S and is 1000x1000. I would want to extract a smaller sub matrix Sred = S([1:600,610:700,800:950,999],[1:600,610:700,800:950,999]).

In fact the matrix is a lot bigger and it takes a significant amount of time to loop through it.

Comment: Hmm. Sadly I'm unfamiliar with matrix notation. you could try using Parallel.For in your outer loop. At least then, you could use all the cores in your cpu. Other than that, I'm not sure what else you could try I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the submatrix is so big and Sparse , it is more efficient to construct it while i am constructing the main matrix. This way i don't have to rewrite a very large number of zeros. This is significantly faster!